# How to cancel list item creation in a list workflow?

Tags: workflow

Is it possible to cancel the creation of a list item in a list workflow?

I know it's possible in an ItemAdding item event receiver, but is it also possible from a workflow?

Using the debugger, it looks like the workflow gets executed AFTER the item is already created.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you only cancel on ItemAdding event handler.